# Django multi db test fails post teardown

Tags: django, django-models, django-testing

My multi-db test problem is the following:

```
# (django 2.0.7, python 3.6)
# settings.py:

DATABASES = {
    'default':{}, 
    'one': { # connection1 settings here }
    'two': { # connection2 settings here }
}
DATABASE_ROUTERS = []

# test.py
class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_my_function(self):
         pass # this IS literally the code
```

I run `python manage.py test -v 2` and see that the test runner builds up the two mock databases and runs the test that is green

```
test_my_function (mymodule.test.MyTestCase) ... ok
```

Then `ERROR` then `ERROR: test_get_pronunciation (languages.test_hr.HRTestCase)`

with the following explanation:

```
File "/Users/Barnabas/PycharmProjects/rhymedict-multisite/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py", line 20, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

This should mean that the program tries to access the `'default'` database.

(The same thing happens if I add `multi_db = True` to my `MyTestCase`)

**Yet** strangely if I write

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    pass
```

The db's are built up, torn down just fine.

What do I do wrong?

### Update:

`self._post_teardown()` raises the error and I can see that both dummy db's are torn down before, successfully.

Comment: Why do you define a `default` anyway, and not just `one` and `two`.

Comment: Otherwise I get `django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection default doesn't exist` when I do `runserver`

Comment: Yes, but why don't you simply define `one` as default, then you have two databases, so no empty one.

Comment: I don't want to do that because this is two separate sites running with mostly the same code. Also `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/` allows my setup.

Answer (score 2):

*Solution:* I need to use `SimpleTestCase` instead of `TestCase`, and voila, problem solved.

The problem happened in `_post_teardown()` that should be an empty function (as it is empty in `TestCase`), but for some reason `TransactionTestCase`'s `_post_teardown()` gets executed instead.

Answer (score 0):

That is how I did to make tests work with two databases, worked like a charm:

```
import sys

if 'test' in sys.argv or 'test_coverage' in sys.argv: 
    DATABASES = {
        'default':{
            'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.sqlite3' # <---- you can add other db connections..
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {},
            'one': { # connection1 settings here }
            'two': { # connection2 settings here }
    }

    # DB routers specification path - case sensitive:
    # ** needs to be within the same scope of DATABASES.
    DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['myapp.routers.db_router.MyRouter']
```

On tests file:

```
class TestModel(TestCase):

    databases = '__all__'

    . . .
```

Comment: Your solution is nice, mind you it only works if you only use 'one' and 'two' as mirrors or backups and you don't need db one and two explicitly for your tests. 
(I ended up just using a single db and prefixing the tables (one_table1, two_table1, etc.) since postgres prefers having less databases. The prefix-approach avoided lots of pain for me.)

Comment: Sure, for me it worked as a charm since, for us, there is a need for more then one db to work with AWS.